# Android-RecyclerView Set Image And Text From JSON

Tags: java, android, json, string, android-fragments

Hi i am trying to make **RecyclerView** List From **JSON** which is sending Image URL and Name *(Only these i need to display to RecyclerView For Now)*. I tried Google and Stack From past 2 days but **Still No Solution To Set Text and Images From JSON to RecyclerView** Most of the tutorials use Volley or Other Library and They use AsyncTask in Same Class (which solve data passing problem ). Which  I am not using

I have successfully made **recyclerView with local images and text Stored in Drawable Folder and In String Array(Values-->String.xml)** and its working fine

But my condition is different then most of the solution

**1)** I am calling AsyncTask.Execute Method From Parent Activity of Fragment

**2)** My AsyncTask Class is not in same class where i am calling AsyncTask.Execute Method.

**3)** I am trying get values in Fragment from AsyncTask which always return Null even after setting setter and getter method (Hard time in transfer Images[] and Name[] to Fragment)

**4)** As i m getting Image Path in String[] then how to set path into Recycler View

Here is my Classes

***From Where I am Calling AsyncTask.Execute Method.

```
      public class Navigation_Drawer extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //Handle Item Selection
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_websearch:    
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have Clicked WebSearch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.parseJson:
                 new JsonParsing().execute();//AYSNCTASK EXECUTE
        }
```

Then That Aysnctask Execute Called This Class

```
   public class JsonParsing extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String[]>> {

private String URL_Path="http://www.example.com/test/Android/Data/showUers.php";
private static final String TAG="JSON PARSER******";
HttpURLConnection connection;
BufferedReader reader;
private Context context;



@Override
protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        URL url=new URL(URL_Path);
        connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        Log.d(TAG,connection.toString());

        InputStream inputStream=connection.getInputStream();
        reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer=new StringBuffer();
        while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            stringBuffer.append(line);

        }
        String completeJSON=stringBuffer.toString();

        JSONArray parentArray=new JSONArray(completeJSON);
        String[] Name=new String[parentArray.length()];
        String[] ImagePath=new String[parentArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i <parentArray.length() ; i++) {
            JSONObject childObject=parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String Fname=childObject.getString("First_Name") ;
            String Lname=childObject.getString("Last_Name") ;

            Name[i]=Fname+" "+Lname;
            ImagePath[i]=childObject.getString("Image");
            Log.d(TAG,"String Arrays "+Name[i]+" "+ ImagePath[i]);
            //THIS LOG SUCCESSFULLY SHOWING RESULT IN LOG


        }

          List<String[]> results=new ArrayList<>(2);
          results.add(Name);
          results.add(ImagePath);
          return results;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        try {
            connection.disconnect();
            if (reader!=null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}





 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String[]> results) {
    Log.d(TAG,"ON POST EXECUTE CALLING START");
    String[] Name=results.get(0);
    String[] Image=results.get(1);
    Log.d(TAG,"ON POST EXECUTE CALLING Bundle");
    FriendsList friendsListFragment=new FriendsList();
    Bundle dataToPass=new Bundle();
    dataToPass.putStringArray("Names",Name);
    dataToPass.putStringArray("ImagePath",Image);
    friendsListFragment.setArguments(dataToPass);
    friendsListFragment.getData(dataToPass);
    Log.d(TAG,"ON POST EXECUTE CALLING LAST "+Name.toString());

}
```

And This Is My Fragment Where I am Calling RecyclerView

```
public class FriendsList extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    TypedArray Image;

    public static final String TAG="Friends List******";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_friend_list,container,false);
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewForFriendList);

        Name=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.left_Drawer_Menu);
        Image=getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.user_image);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter=new RecyclerFriendListAdapter(getActivity(),Name,Image);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        String[] Name=getArguments().getStringArray("Names");//Returns Null
        String[] Image=getArguments().getStringArray("ImagePath");

    return view;
}



public void getData(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        if (savedInstanceState!=null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GET DATA CALLING ");
           String[] New_Name = getArguments().getStringArray("Names");
           String[] New_ImagePath =getArguments().getStringArray("ImagePath");
            Log.d(TAG, "ON CREATE SETTING NAME AND IMAGEPATH INTO ARRAY " + New_ImagePath[2]+" "+New_Name[1]);
            adapter=new RecyclerFriendListAdapter(getActivity(),New_Name,New_ImagePath);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);//*************RETURNS NULL 
            Log.d(TAG, "GET DATA CALLING FINISHED ");


        }
}}
```

Recycler Adapter CLass

```
    public class RecyclerFriendListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerFriendListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    String[] Name,ImagePath;
    TypedArray Image;
    Context context;
    static final String TAG="FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****";


    public RecyclerFriendListAdapter(Context context,String[] name,TypedArray image) {
        this.context = context;
        Image = image;
        Name = name;
    }

 public RecyclerFriendListAdapter(Context context,String[] image, String[] name) {
        this.context=context;
        ImagePath = image;
        Name = name;
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerFriendListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_recycler,null);
        Log.d(TAG,"Constructor Calling");
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerFriendListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Holder "+position);
        holder.UserImage.setImageResource(Image.getResourceId(position,0));
        holder.Name.setText(Name[position]);
       }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Name.length;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView Name;
        ImageView UserImage;
        Context context;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            Log.d(TAG,"View Holder");

            Name= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.User_Name_Item);
            UserImage= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.UserImage);
        }


    }
```

I know i am doing some mistakes in code But I need to do These things

Get Images And Names String Array from doinbackground then get these Values in Fragment and send both array to RecyclerView Adapter to show in recyclerview List.

Its Little Advance Question and only Experts can solve this so please help me resolve this issue

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new JsonParsing.execute();   
        showSkipButton(true);
        setProgressButtonEnabled(true);

    }


      @Override
        public void onDonePressed(Fragment currentFragment) {
            super.onDonePressed(currentFragment);
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,Parent_Activty.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

And This Is Parent Activity Where Fragment is Attached

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.parent_layout);

    //First set up toolbar
    setupToolbar();

    //Add the Fragment to the container
    FragmentTransaction transaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    FriendsList friendList=new FriendsList();
    transaction.replace(R.id.Parent_Main_Layout,friendList);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

New Interface As @Cricket_007 Suggest and Wrapper Class

```
public interface onResultReceived {
    public void onResultRececivedFuc(List<String[]> users);
}
```

Wrapper Class

```
 public  class WrapperClass {

        String[] Name,Image;

        public String[] getName() {
            return Name;
        }

        public void setName(String[] name) {
            Name = name;
        }

        public String[] getImage() {
            return Image;
        }

        public void setImage(String[] image) {
            Image = image;
        }

    }
```

And At Last My Log

```
    08-07 02:17:57.490 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/Friends List******: ON CREATE CALLING 
08-07 02:17:57.490 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/Friends List******: ON CREATE VIEW START
08-07 02:17:57.490 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/Friends List******: PUTTING VALUE INTO NAME AND IMAGE
08-07 02:17:57.490 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/Friends List******: ON CREATE VIEW [Ljava.lang.String;@437092e0
08-07 02:17:57.550 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: Constructor Calling
08-07 02:17:57.550 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: View Holder
08-07 02:17:57.550 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: Holder 0
08-07 02:17:57.600 32184-32188/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 1791K, 42% free 24608K/41927K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 33ms
08-07 02:17:57.600 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
08-07 02:17:57.640 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: Constructor Calling
08-07 02:17:57.640 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: View Holder
08-07 02:17:57.640 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: Holder 1
08-07 02:17:57.650 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: Constructor Calling
08-07 02:17:57.650 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: View Holder
08-07 02:17:57.650 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: Holder 2
08-07 02:17:57.660 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: Constructor Calling
08-07 02:17:57.660 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: View Holder
08-07 02:17:57.660 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: Holder 3
08-07 02:17:57.670 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: Constructor Calling
08-07 02:17:57.670 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: View Holder
08-07 02:17:57.670 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: Holder 4
08-07 02:17:57.680 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: Constructor Calling
08-07 02:17:57.680 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: View Holder
08-07 02:17:57.680 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: Holder 5
08-07 02:17:57.680 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: Constructor Calling
08-07 02:17:57.680 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: View Holder
08-07 02:17:57.690 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/FRIEND LIST ADAPTER****: Holder 6
08-07 02:17:57.700 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/ADAPTER*********: Value of Position0
08-07 02:17:57.700 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/ADAPTER*********: Value of Position1
08-07 02:17:57.710 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/ADAPTER*********: Value of Position2
08-07 02:17:57.720 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/ADAPTER*********: Value of Position3
08-07 02:17:57.720 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/ADAPTER*********: Value of Position4
08-07 02:17:57.730 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/ADAPTER*********: Value of Position5
08-07 02:17:57.730 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/ADAPTER*********: Value of Position6
08-07 02:17:57.740 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/ADAPTER*********: Value of Position7
08-07 02:17:57.740 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/ADAPTER*********: Value of Position8
08-07 02:18:19.830 32184-3367/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/JSON PARSER******: DO IN BACKGROUND START 
08-07 02:18:20.580 32184-3367/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/JSON PARSER******: libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl:DOMAIN NAME/test/Android/Data/showUers.php
08-07 02:18:21.200 32184-3367/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/JSON PARSER******: GET INPUT STREAM AND PUUTING INTO READER
08-07 02:18:21.200 32184-3367/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/JSON PARSER******: JSON ARRAY START
08-07 02:18:21.210 32184-3367/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/JSON PARSER******: String Arrays Julien Blin DOMAIN NAME/test/Android/Data/uploads/Julien.jpg
08-07 02:18:21.210 32184-3367/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/JSON PARSER******: String Arrays Iveta Benesova DOMAIN NAME/test/Android/Data/uploads/Iveta.jpg
08-07 02:18:21.210 32184-3367/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/JSON PARSER******: String Arrays Varun Razora DOMAIN NAME/test/Android/Data/uploads/Varun.jpg
08-07 02:18:21.210 32184-3367/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/JSON PARSER******: JSON PARSING FINISHED
08-07 02:18:21.210 32184-3367/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/JSON PARSER******: Return Statement
08-07 02:18:21.210 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/JSON PARSER******: ON POST EXECUTE CALLING START
08-07 02:18:21.210 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/JSON PARSER******: ON POST EXECUTE CALLING STOP
08-07 02:18:21.210 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/Friends List******: GET DATA CALLING 
08-07 02:18:21.210 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/Friends List******: ON CREATE SETTING NAME AND IMAGEPATH INTO ARRAY DOMAIN NAME/test/Android/Data/uploads/Varun.jpg Iveta Benesova
08-07 02:18:21.210 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-07 02:18:21.210 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416dd378)
08-07 02:18:21.220 32184-32184/com.recyclerview_pro_working1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at com.recyclerview_pro_working1.mainScreenFragments.FriendsList.getData(FriendsList.java:99)
                                                                                   at com.recyclerview_pro_working1.Sending_Image_To_Server.onPostExecute(Sending_Image_To_Server.java:130)
                                                                                   at com.recyclerview_pro_working1.Sending_Image_To_Server.onPostExecute(Sending_Image_To_Server.java:29)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT #1** As @Hendra Wijaya Djiono Suggest I edit my code And Its Returns Null Still and I think its more cause of fragment launch when there is no value (I am calling AsyncTask before too) where i start Parent Activity Like This

**EDIT #2** As both **@Hendra Wijaya Djiono** and **@cricket_007** suggest both answers work as i expect but @Hendra Bundle Point seems easy and clear  and @cricket_007 code suggest avoid bundle i agree with him that bundle would be null when Fragment is created but just for app to work i updated log and code its sending data to fragment via bundle successfully but its comes with 2 more problems first as you can see **recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter) throws null pointer** and how can i set imagePath(URL of Image) to ImageView In adapter.

**EDIT #3** @Cricket_007 Suggested I added Interface and Wrapper Class but putting both string (Name[] and Image[]) Into List List=new ArrayList(); gives me hard time.So i used Noraml List Function and put both string into it then get it into onPostExecute.

Comment: Just so you are aware, there are much easier libraries to use for network requests, and JSON parsing than AsyncTask. You can look at Retrofit to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: Basically, you are trying to return results from an AsyncTask to populate an Adapter. This post covers the data passing piece.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a

Comment: @cricket_007 i know these exist and will make easier but i don't want to include any third party library into current app.It increase app load this thing i avoid that's why i stick to basic functionalities

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried already this link as you can see i wrote that i tried setter and getter method and interface but no luck yet

Comment: In your `onPostExecute`, you made a completely new Fragment, set it's Arguments, but did nothing with that Fragment, so it was never loaded and `onCreateView` was never ran.

Comment: @cricket_007 Actually i edited code as per answer thats's why i made Fragment new object and i am using it as sending results to Fragments as per answer

Comment: I never said make a Wrapper class around two Arrays. My `User` class definition holds 2 Strings, not String arrays.

Comment: @cricket_007 yes you never said about String[] but i need to pass Parse JSON String[] which has different values at each position so i can show into RecyclerView and as per your suggestion am going to implement piccaso for Image setting in ImageView

Comment: I don't know how else to explain what you need to do, but hopefully my edit clarifies something. The adapter takes a *single* `List<User>`, as well... Not two String arrays. Your code should look exactly like mine with `RecyclerFriendListAdapter(getActivity(), users);`

Comment: @cricket_007 As per your code its working fine till onPostExecute and now i need to get into Fragment and then as you suggest i would use picasso (Please suggest if there is any other option without using libs) for convert URL into Bitmap and then display into RecyclerView and one more thing should i save first into Local Storage or Implement direct into List what you suggest. And again thank you so much for you help

Comment: Good to hear. My code should also work in the Fragment, so you just need to update your Adapter. `users.get(position).getImage()`, for example, would get you the image URL, and simply load that with Picasso. If you don't want to use libs, then the Android Documentation tells exactly how to load a Bitmap from an AsyncTask. I don't know what you mean by "local storage", but Picasso handles image caching for you. https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html#async-task

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks and i will update you soon with final outcome. Thanks For your support

Comment: @cricket_007 can you please tell me how to get length of List<WrapperClass> in getItemCount() in Adapter cuz I tried to get it by 

`public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d(TAG,"Size of List "+UsersList.size()); //NULL RETURNS
        return UsersList.size();

    }`

Comment: Well, you didn't initialize the list. I'd recommend you post a new question with your most updated code. I think this post has been answered in enough detail already

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To address the update

`getActivity` has returned you null when you declare the adapter because you made an completely new, empty Fragment, didn't attach it to an Activity.

Then, the second issue is you pass a new Bundle into the `getData` method, but you don't even use that `savedInstanceState` parameter, you instead used `getArguments`. Overall, as written below, **stop using Fragment Bundle arguments**

---

Firstly, make a class to parse your JSON into. You can use Gson or Jackson if you want to simplify that process, but encapsulating these `String[]`'s into a List of objects will make the process easier. And addresses returning multiple `String[]` in the AsyncTask.

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String imageUrl;
    // getters, setters, etc.
}
```

Secondly, (following [How to get the result of OnPostExecute() ... because AsyncTask is a separate class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)) you can define an interface to "call back" to the UI thread with your list of results.

```
public interface AsyncUserResponse {
    public void onUsersReceived(List<User> users);
}
```

Next, you want your AsyncTask to return you a `List<User>`, and you aren't using the String parameters, so you can make that `Void`.

```
public class GetUsersTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<User>> {

    private AsyncUserResponse delegate;
    public GetUsersTask(AsyncUserResponse delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }    

    public List<User> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        List<User> users = new ArraryList<User>();
        // TODO: HTTP Request

        // TODO: Parse JSON string - store into list
        // Loop over some JSON array 
            String name = json.get("name");
            String image = json.get("image_url");
            User u = new User(name, image);
            users.add(u);
        // End loop 
        return users;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(List<User> result) {
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.onUsersReceived(result);
        } 
        // nothing else goes here - this method is done 
    }
}
```

Finally, in order to call that AsyncTask in your Fragment class and get back your results to your adapter, your class can implement that interface, or you can in-line an anonymous class. Your choice.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_friend_list,container,false);

    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewForFriendList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    AsyncUserResponse listener = new AsyncUserResponse() {
        @Override
        public void onUsersReceived(List<User> users) {
            adapter=new RecyclerFriendListAdapter(getActivity(), users);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    };

    new GetUsersTask(listener).execute();


    return view;
}
```

---

Note: You'll additionally need to modify the adapter to take a `List<User>` instead of two String arrays.

Take away here -- Forget the bundle arguments. You are running asynchronous code, so you won't have arguments to get when the Fragment's View is created. This is the same pattern used by Volley, OkHttp, Retrofit, etc. And it is good to understand how they work.

Comment: I will revert back to u soon i am  checking code.Thanks alot

Comment: please check updated log cat i think String array is calling before storing value in Array in `doinbackground` and why onPostExecute Log is not calling or its cuz of app stop log after finishing doinbackground

Comment: Your logs don't match the code, so I don't know what I am looking at. Overall, though, as I said - Forget about the Bundle arguments to the Fragment.

Comment: @androidXP it's a different approach, you use this directly from fragment, so you don't need passing bundle from activity to the fragment. And i agree, instead of pass 2 parameters, you can pass 1 parameter as an object. It will more readable and maintainable

Comment: @cricket_007 Now its match to the code and also check i marge both codes and make new method in fragment to call recycleradapter please check

Comment: @androidXP You are still using arguments and not following the suggestions I provided. You don't even have a `User` class. I can tell you from experience that the approach I've shown works, but you have to follow it from the beginning, not try to integrate into the code you already have that isn't working. I made one edit to my answer that you should see in `onPostExecute` as a comment

Comment: @cricket_007 i am going implement your code but problem is even if i send imagePath to adapter it will throw error cuz i am sending URL to ImageView and i wanted to do it in adapter or i need to run one more thread to convert imagepath into bitmaps. How can i do further coding to set image into RecyclerView. Thanks For Your Support

Comment: Well, first worry about getting the URL into the adapter without errors... But look into the Glide or Picasso libraries for loading the URL into the View. Otherwise, yes, you'll need another task for downloading URL to bitmap

Comment: Still don't know why you don't have a User class, but you are missing the `Received != null` check that's in my answer

Comment: @cricket_007 i tried to implement your code but it throws error at
`@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String[]> results) {
        Log.d(TAG,"ON POST EXECUTE CALLING START");
        if (results!=null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Result is not null "+results.toString());
            Received.onResultRececivedFuc(results); //This Line Throws Null
        }`

Comment: And I just said... You are checking if `results` is null, not `Received` like my answer does. If you implemented it correctly, `results` should never be null, it should be an empty list in the worst case scenario. Plus, it should be a `List`, not an array. In any case, that isn't how you print an array.

Comment: @cricket_007 I Edit code with `WrapperClass` and `Interface` but didn't user Wrapper Cuz I don't have idea how to put both string array into it

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the code you provide isn't clean/robust enough, but to give you some insight, i will use the code you provide.
The first one, if you want to pass both of String[] Name and ImagePath, you and make a 2D array or put both to a List or anything as a wrapper

```
public class JsonParsing extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String[]>> {

    private String URL_Path = "http://www.example.com/test/Android/Data/showUers.php";
    private static final String TAG = "JSON PARSER******";
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    BufferedReader reader;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(URL_Path);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            Log.d(TAG, connection.toString());

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);

            }
            String completeJSON = stringBuffer.toString();

            JSONArray parentArray = new JSONArray(completeJSON);
            String[] Name = new String[parentArray.length()];
            String[] ImagePath = new String[parentArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject childObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String Fname = childObject.getString("First_Name");
                String Lname = childObject.getString("Last_Name");

                Name[i] = Fname + " " + Lname;
                ImagePath[i] = childObject.getString("Image");
                Log.d(TAG, "String Arrays " + Name[i] + " " + ImagePath[i]);
                //THIS LOG SUCCESSFULLY SHOWING RESULT IN LOG

            }

            List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<>(2);
            result.add(Name);
            result.add(ImagePath);

            return result; // CONFUSE IN HOW TO RETURN 2 ARRAY STRING NAME AND IMAGE

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                connection.disconnect();
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String[]> results) {
        //SOMETHING TODO WITH RESULTS
        String[] Name = results.get(0);
        String[] ImagePath = results.get(1);
    }
}
```

To pass the result to your fragment from activity you can use Bundle

```
FriendsList friendsListFragment = new FriendsList();
Bundle dataToPass = new Bundle();
dataToPass.putStringArray("names", Name);
dataToPass.putStringArray("imagePaths", ImagePath);
friendsListFragment.setArguments(dataToPass);
```

On your fragment, you can get the data

```
String[] names = getArguments().getStringArray("names");
String[] imagePaths = getArguments().getStringArray("imagePaths");
```

On your RecyclerView adapter, make a constructor to pass the data

```
private String[] dataName, dataImagePath;

public RecyclerFriendListAdapter(Context context, String[] dataName, String[] dataImagePath) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dataName = dataName;
    this.dataImagePath = dataImagePath;
}
```

And then you can pass the data from your fragment to the adapter via that constructor

Comment: Thank You For your Answer & Help I just tried code you show me but same thing on Fragment it returns Null.Thats How I did in AsyncTask onPostExecute 
`String[] Name=results.get(0);
        String[] Image=results.get(1);
        FriendsList friendsListFragment=new FriendsList();
        Bundle dataToPass=new Bundle();
        dataToPass.putStringArray("Names",Name);
        dataToPass.putStringArray("ImagePath",Image);
        friendsListFragment.setArguments(dataToPass);`

And Getting in Fragments Like this
`String[] Name=getArguments().getStringArray("Names");`

Comment: Really? Can you edit your question and include the new code? And include the stack trace too about the error

Comment: Please check I updated complete code and Thank you for your concern

Comment: You haven't configure your RecyclerFriendListAdapter and FriendsList.onCreateView correctly, please check again

Comment: First i should get the value of String Array on oncreateview then it will send it to RecyclerFriendListAdapter but i am getting null value onCreateView. Thank you

Comment: i think i got the answer just check the updated answer and please help me to please check logcat how `fragment` calls before `onpostexecute`

Comment: well, you still haven't make the constructor with the parameter needed on RecyclerFriendListAdapter and you not passing the parameter correctly on FriendList.onCreateView

Comment: I was made a mistake and already correct it. Should return "List<String[]> result" instead of "String[] Name" on JsonParsing.doInBackground

Comment: Hi please check update code and log now i am getting result back to fragment but please check EDIT part its throws error now